# Why am I getting an invalid API key error when fetching customer data

Tags: react-native

I have the following effect in my react native `app.js`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          if (Platform.OS == "android") {
          console.log(googlePlayAPI)
          await Purchases.configure({ apiKey:googlePlayAPI });
        } else {
          await Purchases.configure({ apiKey: APIKeys.apple });
        }
         try {
            const customerInfo = await Purchases.getCustomerInfo();
            if (typeof customerInfo.entitlements.active.pro !== "undefined") {
              setPro(true)
            }
          } catch (e) {
              alert("customer error " + JSON.stringify(e))
           //This is where the error is occuring
          }
           try {
                  const offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
                  alert(JSON.stringify(offerings))
                   if (offerings.current !== null && offerings.current.availablePackages.length !== 0) {
                    setCurrentOffering(offerings.current.availablePackages[0]);
                  }
            } catch (e) {
              alert('Error getting offers ' + JSON.stringify(e));
            }
        };

        if(!__DEV__){
            Purchases.setLogLevel(Purchases.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE)
            fetchData()
                .catch(console.log);
        }
      }, []);
```

Purchases is imported as follows:

```
import Purchases from 'react-native-purchases';
```

The `console.log(googlePlayAPI)` line is outputing the same public API key as stated in my project on Revenue Cat. but I am getting an "InvalidCredentialsError", with an underlying error message of "Invalid API Key".

What am I doing wrong?